# # of vertices and # of connected components proof problem?

Tags: graph-theory, pigeonhole-principle

Let G be a graph with 15 vertices and 4 connected components. Prove that G
has at least one component with at least 4 vertices. What is the largest number of vertices that a component of G can have?

Read over connected components for a long time and still have no idea how to prove this.

Answer (score 1):

For the first, think about the pigeonhole principle.  If each component has three vertices or less, how many vertices can there be?  For the second, you want three of the components to have as few vertices as possible to leave as many as possible for the big one.

Comment: I haven't been taught the pigeon principle yet in my graph theory class yet.  I don't think I can use it.

Comment: Assume the contrary--that each of your components has less than 4 vertices. (So at most 3 vertices per component). What is your maximum possible number of vertices? What does this contradict?

Comment: The [pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle) is not part of graph theory, it is just about counting things.  When stated, it seems obvious, but it is extremely useful.

Comment: @Useless I am still confused.  Are you saying think about 15 vertices and there are 4 connected components.  Then each vertex has at most 3 vertices?  Why would this contradict ? :/

Comment: If each of the four components has three vertices the total number of vertices is $12$, so you can't have $15$.

Comment: @Millikan just figured this out.  Thanks everybody!